# How to easily print object properties and methods in scala?

Tags: scala, influxdb

I am using this client (https://github.com/paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client) to connect to influxdb database that returns an object. I need to access some of its properties to know what is inside !

I have written the following code :
`results(0).forEach((k, v) => { println(k, v)})`
Error message : 
value forEach is not a member of com.paulgoldbaum.influxdbclient.Series

I also tried : 
`for ((key, value) <- result) { println(key, value) }` 
Error Message : 
value withFilter is not a member of com.paulgoldbaum.influxdbclient.Series

I am fairly new to scala but I don't understand how come there is no easy way to inspect an object !? Properties, methods ...
Please HELP !

Comment: Have you tried  `result.series.head.records.foreach(println)`?

Comment: Also, you receive a "Future[QueryResult]" when you query the database. Are you handling the Future correctly?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik : Yes the result is => ```com.paulgoldbaum.influxdbclient.Record@48defbb0```
I don't see the content of the object just its reference !

Comment: I just want to pretty print a scala object, I couldn't find any way to do it !

Comment: Maybe try `result.series.head.records.foreach(r => println(r.allValues))`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik : This works for printing the elements of result.series.head.records because it is a list and the method as been implemented by the developper (see code here : https://github.com/paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/paulgoldbaum/influxdbclient/QueryResult.scala, line 9 and 23) but i still can't print all the properties of an object as a general pretty-print method or something like this ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik : I don't understand tough what he does when he implements the method allValues to explore the project ...   
```class Record protected[influxdbclient] 
(namesIndex: Map[String, Int], values: List[Any]) {
  def apply(position: Int) = values(position)
  def apply(name: String) = values(namesIndex(name))
  def allValues = values
}```

What does ```def allValues = values ``` do ?

Comment: It just returns what field `values` hold.
Basically printing objects in Java and Scala work like that: If the method has method `toString` defined, then it is used, if not then console prints `fully.qualified.name@somehash` and that is what you see with the `Record`.